# wildcards in chef attributes

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, nested-attributes

I am trying to get the version of an installed package Firefox from OHAI for a windows machine

The output of ohai contains packages info like

```
 "ohai_time": 1540893742.872569,
 "packages": {
 "Mozilla Firefox 62.0.2 (x64 en-US)": {
 "version": "62.0.2",
 "publisher": "Mozilla"
 },
 "Mozilla Maintenance Service": {
 "version": "62.0.2",
 "publisher": "Mozilla"
 },
 "Symantec NetBackup Client": {
 "version": "7.7.2",
 "publisher": "Symantec Corporation",
 "installdate": "20180618"
  }, .....
  ......so on...
```

the problem is that I cannot use the full name that is used here because it contains the version itself

otherwise i could use 
node['packages']['Mozilla Firefox 62.0.2 (x64 en-US)']['version']

Instead I want to use something like node['packages']["Mozilla*"]['version']

I have tried using loops and .include? But did not work.
What are my options here? Using ruby or loops or anything else

Thanks for you responses in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of a hash like you have pasted you could use [`find`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) method:

```
node["packages"].find { |key, _| key =~ /Mozilla Firefox/ }
 => [:"Mozilla Firefox 62.0.2 (x64 en-US)", {:version=>"62.0.2", :publisher=>"Mozilla"}]
```

Just keep in mind it will convert your hash to an array, but it can be easily reverted.